# How to remove the vertical space generated changepage package's adjustwidth

Tags: vertical-spacing, vspace, adjustwidth, changepage

Consider the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{testenvironment}[2]{
    \textbf{#1} \textbf{#2}
    
    % \vspace*{-6pt} % <--- this is a workaround to fix the vertical space generated by adjustwidth
                     %      but it creates another vertical space problem if adjustwidth has contents
    \begin{adjustwidth}{8pt}{8pt} % <--- this adds a vertical space
}
{
    \end{adjustwidth}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}
\end{testenvironment}

\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}
\end{testenvironment}

\end{document}
```

It generates this:

[image: output]

Notice that there is a significant vertical space between two lines. If I comment the `adjustwidth` environment (i.e., `\begin{adjustwidth}{8pt}{8pt}` and `\end{adjustwidth}`), then it removes the extra vertical space. But I want to use `adjustwidth`'s feature without the vertical space. The commented line above `adjustwidth` (`\vspace*{-6pt}`) is a workaround to remove the vertical spacing but it creates another vertical spacing problem if `adjustwidth` has text inside (i.e., `\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2} hello \end{testenvironment}`).

So how to remove the extra vertical space generated by `adjustwidth`?

Comment: tabu is broken and unmaintained, see the readme here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks! I have removed the `tabu` package reference since it is also not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove one `\baselineskip` of space if the environment ends in vertical mode (eg if it is empty)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% not needed in current latex \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{testenvironment}[2]{% dont forget eol
    \textbf{#1} \textbf{#2}%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{8pt}{8pt}% <--- this adds a vertical space
}
{%
\ifvmode\mbox{}\par\nobreak\vspace{-\baselineskip}\fi
    \end{adjustwidth}%
}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}%
\end{testenvironment}


\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}
testenvironment % no extra space with added text line
\end{testenvironment}

\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}
testenvironment % no extra space with added text line

\end{testenvironment}

\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}
testenvironment % no extra space with added text line
\end{testenvironment}

\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}
testenvironment % no extra space with added text line

\end{testenvironment}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to consider as below:

```
% adjustprob.tex  Modified MWE from SE 559287

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{testenvironment}[2]{
    \textbf{#1} \textbf{#2}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{8pt}{8pt} % <--- this adds a vertical space
}
{
    \end{adjustwidth}%
}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}
% \mbox{ } % doesn't work for some reason
\end{testenvironment}
\vspace{-1em} % remove space after the environment

\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}
testenvironment % no extra space with added text line
\end{testenvironment}

\begin{testenvironment}{Column1}{Column2}
testenvironment % no extra space with added text line
\end{testenvironment}

\end{document}
```

When additional text is put in `testenvironment` there is no extra vertical space. If there is no additional text then there is extra vertical space which can be removed by putting `\vspace{-1em} after the` testenvironment` ends.

I don't know why the `\mbox{}` is not treated as additional invisible text.

Comment: If there is a way to create `testenvironment` that does not generate the extra space regardless of having blank content or some contents in the environment, that would be good to know. If I need to add `\vspace{-1em}` manually for blank content, then I could do that without creating the environment. I created the environment not to do any manual things such as `\vspace{-1em}`

Comment: `\mbox` is working in exactly the same way as text, making a one line paragraph.